# How to make text fixed to console screen using c++ on windows cmd?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

So i've used programs like htop using bash and they have cool ways of showing data. It does things like having a fixed bar that shows what buttons you can push and what they do.

[image]

The bottom row of commands is fixed to the screen so it won't move when you scroll. Is there any way for me to program this kind of behavior into a windows cmd c++ application? If so, how?

Comment: Check out [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: I'm not sure if that works with windows

Comment: D'oh.  Missed that.  [this](https://www.projectpluto.com/win32a.htm#flavors) alternative might work.

Comment: Use the windows [console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)